# QGIS fails to load

Tags: qgis, python, installation, ubuntu

I installed some python libraries using pip (pandas, scipy, simplekml) and ever since every time I try to load QGIS I get this error:

```
Warning: loading of qgis translation failed
[/usr/share/qgis/i18n//qgis_en_US]
Warning: loading of qt translation failed
[/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_US]
Warning: QCss::Parser - Failed to load file  "/style.qss" 
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
QH6248 qh_lib_check: Incorrect qhull library called.  Caller uses reentrant Qhull while library is non-reentrant
QH6249 qh_lib_check: Incorrect qhull library called.  Size of qhT for caller is 8184, but for library is 2896.
QH6255 qh_lib_check: Cannot continue.  Library 'qhull 7.2.0 (2015.2 2016/01/18)' uses a dynamic qhT via qh_QHpointer (e.g., qhull_p.so)
```

What is wrong? How can I fix it ? I have version 2.14. Should I remove it? Or maybe remove qhull library ?

Comment: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/5169 check this once

Comment: This suggests to remove python qgis. I need it though

Comment: Try 'qgis --noplugins', if it starts then problem may be due to some plugin

Comment: Can you add which Ubuntu version, and which QGIS repo you used? And maybe run `apt-cache rdepends libqhull*`.From the qgis/debian repo, I only get the third warning, and libqhull7.

Comment: Ubuntu version: 16.04  I installed from ubuntu gis repo  (http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu)   By running this command, I get a list of reverse depends. Which one is of interest ?   I'm sure something happened yesterday that I installed these libraries..... :-(

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the latest packages in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Well... I'm one release behind if you mean that. Latest is 2.18.4  and I am still on 2.14

Comment: what is I remove this qhull library ???

Comment: All packages listed with `rdepends` will be removed too. From my list, it will be at least saga. I'm not sure if one of the others are used by QGIS. It might be that pip has overwritten libs that are installed by QGIS.

Comment: Same problem here on Linux Mint.

Comment: @AndreJ this is what apt-cache rdepends libhull* gives me   https://pastebin.com/DBfzNhLC     Any idea how to fix it my problem ?

Comment: The gdal-abi problem also affects QGIS 2.14.13, so updating QGIS is not recommended at this point.  From your rdepends list, you see libgdal20 listed, so this will be removed if you delete libqhull. You might switch to the qgis.org/debian repo which is not affected.

Comment: Does this mean I uninstall this version and remove ubuntu gis stable ppa ? then add debian repo ?

Comment: Just tested: If you remove the qgis/ubuntugis repo, you can take QGIS 2.14.11 from ubuntugis-unstable solely, and it works. libqhull7 is version 2015.2-1 from 15 Feb 2016, that seems to be newer than what you have got via pip.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56289/discussion-on-question-by-stefanos-qgis-fails-to-load).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Got the same problem on Linux Mint and finally fixed it.

The problem is that you've installed a few python libraries and one of them is a dependency of QGIS.

QGIS ~2.18 works fine with Scipy 0.17, and after upgrade this library to the newest version you have 0.19.

QGIS won't load with 0.19 because libqhull error.

All you need to do is downgrade, simply:

```
pip install scipy==0.17
```

And everything should be ok. You can also try with newer version but I'm not sure which one is good. I downgraded to 0.11 and it works form me again.

Comment: The main Ubuntu repo has python-scipy version 0.17.0 for xenial, if you prefer using packages instead of pip.

Comment: Dude...!!! You saved me..!  I downgraded and it works. Although on startup QGIS shows a message that a plugin has been disabled due to last crash. Thanks  ^_^   @AndreJ  You mean instead of pip I should be using synaptic?

Comment: Synaptic or `sudo apt-get install`. It works better with QGIS and GDAL packages.

Comment: You can always use virtualenv http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: `scipy==0.17` seems to be the newest version that works with QGIS 2.14

Comment: @dmh126: you might update your answer to reflect that anything up to 0.17 will work.

Comment: Also, @dmh126, if you could spell out how to do that, it might be a better answer. I do not really want to downgrade scipy from 0.19 because I use it for other stuff, so the current answer is a poor compromise for me.

Comment: Worked for me as well, using Ubuntu 16 LTS, downgraded scipy, all good.

Answer (score 2):

The same problem was pestering my QGIS on Fedora 27 for some time. QGIS was working fine, but if I wanted to install qgis-python, the libqhull error has prevented QGIS to start.

I did an ugly trick with compiling libqhull from the source and just overwrote the /usr/lib64/libqhull.so.7.2.0 with the manually compiled version and the problem was gone. The whole procedure was like:

1. Install qgis-devel

   ```
   dnf install qgis-devel
   ```

   (so the QGIS is broken and can not start)
2. Download qhull source, compile and overwrite the libqhull library

   ```
   cd /usr/local/src
   wget http://www.qhull.org/download/qhull-2015-src-7.2.0.tgz
   tar xzvf qhull-2015-src-7.2.0.tgz
   cd qhull-2015.2
   make
   cp -p lib/libqhull_r.so.7.2.0 /usr/lib64/libqhull.so.7.2.0
   ```
3. The QGIS should now run with Python Console enabled