# QGIS 3.2 installation error on Ubuntu 16

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

I am installing QGIS, I added the repository and cleaned my machine of any QGIS Packages, I tried removing and reinstalling qgis-providers but the same issue occurred again (see error-message):

```
Setting up qgis-providers-common (1:3.2.3+24xenial-ubuntugis) ...
Setting up qgis-providers (1:3.2.3+24xenial-ubuntugis) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.3.2.3: undefined symbol: OGR_F_SetFieldNull
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up libjs-leaflet (1.0.3+dfsg-1~xenial0) ...
Setting up qgis-common (1:3.2.3+24xenial-ubuntugis) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:3.2.3+24xenial-ubuntugis); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up qgis-plugin-grass-common (1:3.2.3+24xenial-ubuntugis) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Setting up qgis-provider-grass (1:3.2.3+24xenial-ubuntugis) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 1:3.2.3+24xenial-ubuntugis); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-plugin-grass
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: try with this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/287948/49538

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258945/undefined-symbol-ogr-f-setfieldnull-when-installing-qgis Make sure to have the correct scipy version.