# QGIS is not starting

Tags: qgis, ubuntugis, scipy

My QGIS Installation is not loading after startup, cause of an error thrown. I have looked in similiar topics like [QGIS fails to load](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234010/qgis-fails-to-load/261506?noredirect=1#comment414199_261506) and tried all of the options available. I changed to scipy 0.17 and 0.11, removed qgis entirely, removed qlibhull7, installed all again, removed .qgis2, tried to start with --noplugins. Nothing worked so far.

my default installation:

- qgis 2.18
- ubuntu 16.04
- scipy 1.0.0

it's always the same error

```
Warning: loading of qgis translation failed [/usr/share/qgis/i18n//qgis_en_US]
Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_US]
Warning: QCss::Parser - Failed to load file  "/style.qss" 
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: No such file or directory
Warning: QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /home/cheeseman/.qgis2//project_templates
Warning: QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QgsPanelWidgetStack "mWidgetStack", which already has a layout
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
QH6248 qh_lib_check: Incorrect qhull library called.  Caller uses reentrant Qhull while library is non-reentrant
QH6249 qh_lib_check: Incorrect qhull library called.  Size of qhT for caller is 8184, but for library is 2896.
QH6255 qh_lib_check: Cannot continue.  Library 'qhull 7.2.0 (2015.2 2016/01/18)' uses a dynamic qhT via qh_QHpointer (e.g., qhull_p.so)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the debian repository instead of the ubuntugis one? I had some troubles with ubuntugis before but I am not sure if this is the case